# How to Set an Open Explorer Window to be Topmost in PowerShell Without Extra Modules?

Tags: powershell, window, focus, microsoft-file-explorer

In PowerShell how can I set an open explorer window topmost without any extra modules

the explorer window is is c:\users\public\fonts

Regards

I found this one liner `(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate((get-process notepad).MainWindowTitle)` but it doesn't work for explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a window *topmost* is different from *activating* it:

- The *topmost* window remains visible in front of all other windows *whether or not it is the active window*.
- The *active* window is the one with the *input focus* (the one that respond to *user input*), which is by default also the one visible in front of all other windows - but may be preempted as such by the window designated as *topmost*.

---

It looks like *activating* a window *by its title* is what you're looking for:

```bash
$null = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate('c:\users\public\fonts')
```

- For predictable activation, specify the window title exactly as shown in the File Explorer window of interest - except that case does *not* matter.
- The `.AppActivate()` method seemingly also accepts *substrings* of window titles, though the exact requirements for what substrings constitute a match aren't clear.